# Does the definition of the upper case incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(a,x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t}\ t^{a-1}$ hold for any integer $a$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

The question is about the definition of upper and lower incomplete gamma functions.
In [1] we can see :

> **Lower case:**
>   $$
> \gamma(a,x)=\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t} \ t^{a-1}\;dt \quad;\quad \text{Re}(a)>0
> $$
>
> **Upper case:**
>   $$
> \Gamma(a,x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t}\ t^{a-1} \;dt
> $$

Now,

> **Question:** Does the Upper case relation hold for any integer $a$ ?

---

**Reference** :

[1] Higher Transcendental functions, vol 2 page 133, Erdelyi, A., et al.

Comment: It holds for any *complex* $a$ s.t. $\Re(a)>0$.

Comment: based on what ?

Comment: i think this is coming from the convergence issues, does it ?

Comment: $\lim_{x->\infty}e^{-x}x^n=0$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: but the below textbook does not determine any condition on $a$ ? its weird, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the definition of $\Gamma$ holds for all $a$, as the singularity  at $t=0$ is avoided.

Also check the comments about the integration path in [NIST](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2).

$\gamma$ can be extended by means of $$\gamma(a,z)+\Gamma(a,z)=\Gamma(a).$$

Comment: therefore we must have:
 $\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t}\ t^{-2-1}dt = \Gamma(-2, x)$

can we say 

$ \Gamma(-2,x) = E_{3}(x)$
?

Comment: The singularity at $t=0$ is avoided only when $x>0$.