# How to compute the incomplete Gamma function with an negetive parameter in MATLAB?

Tags: integration, matlab, gamma-function

I need to compute the upper incomplete gamma function  $$\Gamma(-0.5,0.5r)$$ 
But in MATLAB, the upper incomplete Gamma function "gammainc" is defined as
$$\Gamma\left(\alpha ; x\right) = \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int\limits_{x}^{\infty}t^{\alpha - 1}e^{-t}\text{ d}t\text{.}$$ with parameter $\alpha > 0$.

When I type "**gammainc(0.5,-0.5*1,'upper')**", the MATLAB says "**Error using gammainc, A must be real and non-negative!**"

But actually what I want to get is defined as this From [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html):
$$\Gamma(\alpha;x) = \int\limits_{x}^{\infty}t^{a-1}e^{-t}\text{ d}t\text{.}$$
So what do I have to do to get the results in MATLAB ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the incomplete Gamma function, but according to Wikipedia, it is only defined for $\alpha > 0$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: see : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363278/i-have-question-about-incomplete-gamma-functions

Answer (score 2):

Here's a MATLAB function that claims to compute the upper incomplete Gamma function for negative $\alpha$: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29321-evaluation-of-the-upper-incomplete-gamma-function/content/gamma_incomplete.m

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much ! It is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Please notice, in the Matlab Function (gammainc(x,a)) , the position of $\alpha$ and x is different, see the help. Due to the help, you should enter the codes as below:

$$ \Gamma(a,x) = {\Gamma(\alpha)}\ * \ gammainc(x,a,'upper')$$

In fact, it returns regularized incomplete Gamma function

Otherwise, if you know this tip check below:

[Does the definition of the upper case incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(a,x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t}\ t^{a-1}$ hold for any integer $a$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363278/i-have-question-about-incomplete-gamma-functions)

Comment: I did notice the position,and I did type it in the right position; the  limit of integration x= 0.5 comes in the first, and then the $\alpha = -0.5$.  Just like this, "gammainc(0.5,-0.5*1,'upper')".

Comment: @panyijin see the link, i was asked this question couple days ago, it have your answer

Comment: Oh, thanks!  The answers are very helpful! But in this case, I want to figure it out in matlab.

Answer (score 1):

Please use "igamma(a,z)", this Matlab function supports negative "a".

https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/igamma.html